# RSC template fancyhdr doesn't respond well!

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I am using RSC latex template (https://www.latextemplates.com/template/royal-society-of-chemistry) to write my research article using Texliv and the margin at bottom is not well aligned (see image attached). It shows that header is shifted down. Before Texliv, I was using Miktex and it was working well. I don't understand the problem.
Please help me to solve out this.
Thanks in advance.

[image: margin problem at bottom]

Comment: Welcome to tex.stack...

Answer (score 2):

I also came across with the same problem. To fix this you have to download the following files in your source folder (i.e., the folder containing the main TeX file).

- `balance.sty`
- `caption.sty`
- `caption3.sty`
- `fancyhdr.sty`
- `mhchem.sty`
- `secsty.sty`

You will get these files for download from the following link:

https://github.com/bardsoftware/template-RSC/tree/master/Paper

After downloading these files in your source folder, execute your TeX file and it works fine.

Comment: You saved me from madness.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to a change in the `fancyhdr` package: [What has changed in LaTeX that means the RSC template no longer works](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/491859/what-has-changed-in-latex-that-means-the-rsc-template-no-longer-works#comment1242180_491859)​

I've added an answer there which does not require adding `.sty` files for previous package versions.