# \multirow with top-align functionality incompatibility issue?

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, multirow, incompatibility, overleaf

I am working on a document, in Overleaf, using \multirow in the usual fashion to make my tables look less crowded. I would like to vertical (top) align my multirow cells. However, I'm seeing unexpected behaviour.

`\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{2}}` gives normal behaviour (bold '2' centered vertically)

`\multirow[t]{2}{*}{\textbf{2}}` gives an error: "Missing number treated as zero. Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)." Followed by Overfull errors, presumably caused the automatic insertion to fix the first and second errors. Compiled I get black boxes in my table with "[t]" printed, although it *is* top aligned.

I have tried to recreate this error in a new document, but I see only the expected behaviour! I have a lot of other packages in use and formatting on the document (I need to use a proprietary template) - are there any incompatibilities that I should investigate. Is there a common mistake I am making?

Previous (solved) questions have cited possible incompatibility with \siunitx: [one fixed with extra braces around \multirow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/368679/siunitx-incompatible-with-multirow) and [one fixed with \tablenum](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/356827/problem-with-siunitx-and-multirow/356851). I am using \siunitx, but the errors I'm getting are different from those reported previously and the solutions did not work in this case.

Simplified code (Note: this works!! - the same code in my document does not.):

```
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
   detect-mode,
   detect-family,
   detect-inline-family=math,
}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{table*}
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}llrrrrrr}
    \hline
    A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H \\
    \hline
    \multirow[t]{4}{*}{\textbf{1}} & i & 1 & 2 & 1.0 & \num{-2} & 0.0 & 6.0 \\
    & ii & 1.0 & 103 & 04 & 1 & 0.4 & 10 \\
    & iii & 2.5 & 6 & 0.06 & 0.78 & \num{-0.8} & 6.2 \\
    & iv & 1.3 & 35 & 2 & \num{-10} & 0.06 & 1 \\
    \multirow[t]{2}{*}{\textbf{2}}& v & 80 & 1 & 0.44 & 0.80 & 0.22 & 2 \\
    & vi & 100 & 12.31 & 0.02 & 0.30 & \num{-1.16} & 1 \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular*}
\end{table*}
```

Comment: _[Disclaimer: I'm a support personnel at Overleaf.]_I just tested your short example in an Overleaf project, and it compiles without any problems. Are you able to abbreviate, from your non-working project, an example that indeed errors out, and post it here? If not, you may want to contact support@overleaf.com providing your project's URL, so that the Support team can have a look at your project directly.

Comment: @LianTzeLim Yes, I am also struggling to recreate the error. I will email as you suggest.

Comment: With thanks to @LianTzeLim, the solution has already been posted [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/524603/187545).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was due to the Overleaf project using TeX Live 2016, at which time, the vertical alignment functionality was not present in \multirow.

With the project changed to use TL2019, changes had to be made to the template I was using. A similar question (that I didn't see previously) was posted [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/491859/what-has-changed-in-latex-that-means-the-rsc-template-no-longer-works/524603) and @LianTzeLim posted a solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/524603/187545).